# How to denote a function that depends on $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ without the dots?

Tags: notation

I know that I can wrote something like $$a_1 + \cdots + a_n$$ without the dots as $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$ which seems clearer to me. As a programmer, I'd rather have a rule set with variables than something with dots where I have to extract the pattern from.

Is there some notation to do this for the parameters of a function? Say a Lagrangian like so: $$L\left(q_1, \ldots, q_n, \dot q_1, \ldots, \dot q_n, t\right)$$

The thought in the back of my head is the following. In Python, I could have a function like so:

```
f(x, y, z)
```

When I call that function, I could either to `f(1, 2, 3)` or I could do the following:

```
parameters = [1, 2, 3]
f(*parameters)
```

Where I basically “dump” that list of parameters into the parenteses of the function. Is there some math notation for the same thing?

Comment: I think it's worth noting that even with $\sum_{i=1}^n$, there is a standard interpretation that is not really any more explicit than $a_1+\cdots+a_n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if that's what you're looking for, but we do that last thing in $\mathbb R^n$ usually ; the vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ are defined as vectors of the form 
$$
(x_1, \dots, x_n), \qquad x_i \in \mathbb R
$$
but if we write $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, when defining a function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ for instance, we can just write $f(x)$ instead of $f(x_1, \dots,x_n)$. Is that what you were looking for?

For your Lagrangian for instance, you could define $q = (q_1, \dots, q_n)$, $\dot q = (\dot q_1, \dots, \dot q_n)$, and write 
$$
L(q,\dot q, t) 
$$
instead of 
$$
L(q_1, \dots, q_n, \dot q_1, \dots, \dot q_n, t).
$$

Hope that helps,

Comment: Well, $L\left(\vec{q}, \vec{\dot q}, t\right)$ seems clean and to the point. Defining vectors is probably the thing I am looking for!

Comment: @queueoverflow : I added something. Oh and you don't need to put arrows over the vectors. These are for children. =)

Comment: I see that the vector arrows are not used so much at university. They even write $\int \mathrm dx$ when I would write $\iiint \mathrm dV$ :-)

Comment: @queueoverflow : When one does measure theory he also often writes $\int_X f$. So yeah, arrows for children. Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

According to one professor of mine, $\underline{x} = x_1, \dots , x_n$.

Comment: One professor of mine used the underscore for matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $\{x_i\}_{i\leq n}$ instead of $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$.

Comment: True. But how can I make a set the parameters of a function?

Comment: queueoverflow: What's wrong with $f(\{x_i\}_{i\leq n})$?

Comment: Maybe I am too much programmer here, but then $f$ is a function which domain is a set, not a bunch of variables.

Comment: Then redefine your function's domain to $n$-uples. IMO you shouldn't emphasize so much on this; after all it's just notation. Humans are not computers, as long as your notation isn't ambiguous there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: $n$-tuples $\neq$ sets. The order of the elements matters in $n$-tuples.